# Controlling 15amp outlet for compressor with Honeywell RC840T-120 and 18g wire to toggle

Tags: relay, 120v

I have a compressor in my crawlspace that I'd like to turn on by using a low volt toggle.

I was planning to use Honeywell RC840T-120 such that my 18g wire is hooked up to the 24v leads and causes the relay to activate the 120 in the outlet.

Any issues with this approach?

Comment: What're the compressor ratings? What are the relay contact ratings? Most relays have a lower  motor rating (typically in HP) than you'd expect from their resistive current rating, due to the inductive and starting load aspects of motors.

Comment: Do you ever drain the water from the tank, with it located so inconveniently? I suppose it's probably oilless, as changing the oil would also be a pain - in which case the pump will likely wear out before the tank rusts out anyway...

Comment: I drain the tank every once and a while...   how often should I be draining it ?  Tank does take oil but I might swap it out.  It is a cheapo 8 gallon hotdog compressor on wheels.

Comment: Have you considered simplifying things by just switching the outlet with a mechanical motor load rated switch? Crawl space to ground floor wiring is usually pretty easy. (I also searched for smart plugs, but couldn’t find anything that would work with a big compressor style load.)

Comment: I'd have to go two floors up with the wiring....  maybe I could do the mechanical motor rated switch a floor up and get half way there...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> "The RC840T Electric Heating Relay is designed to control a line
> voltage resistive load"

[Source](https://customer.honeywell.com/resources/techlit/TechLitDocuments/69-0000s/69-2562EF.pdf)

So asking it to control a motor load, particularly one that starts as hard as the typical compressor, is probably a BAD idea. If the compressor is a fish-tank air pump, perhaps not a worry. If it's a shop air compressor, not a good idea at all. Airbrush compressor, probably yes unless it's abnormally huge.

Later in the specs it does claim it can handle a 0.8 HP inductive load  (motor) on 120V so if the compressor motor is 3/4 HP or smaller, *perhaps* you're OK using it.

*Unfortunately you have to get into quite big compressors before some of them have the sense to include an unloader so the motor can get up to speed before the pump starts pumping air. I don't think any that would plug into a 120V outlet have that feature.*

Comment: 8 Gal, 2 peak HP, 95-125psi, 3.5 scfm @ 90 psi, 60LBS, 12amp  are the stats for the air compressor

Comment: 3,400 pump rpm induction motor

Comment: Can you recommend a relay that would work well for this compressor ?

Comment: Pretty much any contactor (an alternate term for a hefty relay that may get better results) or relay rated for 2 or more HP and with a 24V coil, if you want to control it with 24V ... Though "peak HP" is utter Male Bovine Food Byproduct in motor ratings...

Comment: would this work?  https://www.canadabreakers.ca/products/lc1d32g7  I'd need to buy an enclosure with a din rail as well ?

Comment: That one says it has a 120VAC coil, and ou seemed to want 24VAC, but otherwise, yes. Or you could use the 24V coil honeywell to switch the 120V coil of this one. I think you can buy a big enough "blank" enclosure and screw some DIN rail to the back of it, rather than needing to find one pre-installed.